# Heroku + Paperclip Access Denied even with IAM Policies set

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, heroku, amazon-s3

I have been trying to get paperclip to work with my heroku app and I keep running into the seeminly common Access Denied Error.

My process of trying to fix it has been this.

1. Instead of using root Access Keys, I changed it to a User and used it's Access key.
2. For the user I went to Permissions -> Attach Policy ->
   AdministratorAccess (usually fixes the problem)
3. After that I went Permissions -> Attach Policy -> AmazonS3FullAccess.

After all this, I am still getting the same access denied error.

The heroku logs look like this.

```
2016-03-17T10:40:08.879149+00:00 app[web.1]: [paperclip] saving /posts/herobgs/000/000/002/original/I5APPDXHX3.jpg
2016-03-17T10:40:08.912162+00:00 app[web.1]: [AWS S3 403 0.03225 0 retries] put_object(:acl=>:public_read,:bucket_name=>"your_bucket_name",:content_length=>1584235,:content_type=>"image/jpeg",:data=>Paperclip::UploadedFileAdapter: I5APPDXHX3.jpg,:key=>"posts/herobgs/000/000/002/original/I5APPDXHX3.jpg") AWS::S3::Errors::AccessDenied Access Denied
2016-03-17T10:40:08.912179+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-03-17T10:40:08.913506+00:00 app[web.1]:    (0.9ms)  ROLLBACK
2016-03-17T10:40:08.913736+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 3930ms (ActiveRecord: 3.7ms)
2016-03-17T10:40:08.914580+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-03-17T10:40:08.914589+00:00 app[web.1]: AWS::S3::Errors::AccessDenied (Access Denied):
2016-03-17T10:40:08.914590+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:33:in `update'
2016-03-17T10:40:08.914591+00:00 app[web.1]:
```

Comment: Are you definitely using those credentials? Is the "your_bucket_name" what is actually in the logs?

Comment: Yeah that's what it actually says. Which is weird because I've also checked the Heroku Config and the production.rb and both say something different

Comment: Sounds like you haven't configured the bucket to use then